# plotly.io.write_image() changes my given filepath by adding "/" which makes the path useless

Tags: python, plotly

I want to save some plotly graph object figures as a svg file. My code looks like this:

```
import plotly.io as pio
pio.write_image(figOIA, "S:\FC\FCD\06_Datenbanken\FCD Dashboard\Plots Budget-Ausschöpfung/asdf.svg"))
```

But I get an error saying this:

```
>     OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'S:\\FC\\FCD\x06_Datenbanken\\FCD Dashboard\\Plots
> Budget-Ausschöpfung/asdf.svg'
```

Apparently, the write_image() function changed my directory. Why is it adding the "/" and the "x" in front of "06_Datenbanken" ? It's so frustrating as I have no clue how that can happen, any help is highly aprreciated, thank you!

From the answers I know now what the mistake was. But when I now try this code:

```
 raw_string = r"S:\FC\FCD\06_Datenbanken\FCD Dashboard\Plot Budget-Ausschöpfung" + r"/" + r"{}".format(today.year) + r"_" + r"{}".format(today.month) + r"_" + r"{}".format(Ressort_value) + r"_Budget-Ausschöpfung.svg"
     pio.write_image(figOIA, raw_string )
```

I still get this error:

```
>     FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'S:\\FC\\FCD\\06_Datenbanken\\FCD Dashboard\\Plot
> Budget-Ausschöpfung/2020_7_Alle_Budget-Ausschöpfung.svg'
```

So the double backslashes are still there.. what is wrong this time?

Comment: It's unfortunate that Windows uses the same character for path separators that most languages use for special string escape sequences.  But of course it's for the same reason, the backslash \\ is a rarely used character otherwise.

Comment: Have you tried the latest release? Apparently they added a better support for write static images check [this](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#490---2020-07-16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backslash character `\` is used as a special escape character in Python strings.  In order to defeat this special processing you must either double them up as `\\` or use a raw string.

```
pio.write_image(figOIA, "S:\\FC\\FCD\\06_Datenbanken\\FCD Dashboard\\Plots Budget-Ausschöpfung/asdf.svg"))
```

or

```
pio.write_image(figOIA, r"S:\FC\FCD\06_Datenbanken\FCD Dashboard\Plots Budget-Ausschöpfung/asdf.svg"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! But unfortunately my code still has some errors even with raw strings. I edited my question now.

Comment: @thyhmoo the backslashes are doubled up when you look at the string too, but if you use `print` you won't see that.  I'd say the file really doesn't exist, perhaps because the accented characters aren't being treated properly.